# Python decoding errors with BeautifulSoup, requests, and lxml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, decoding, python-requests

I'm attempting to pull some data off a popular browser based game, but am having trouble with some decoding errors:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.neopets.com/")
p = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

This produces the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__

File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 185, in _feed

File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 195, in feed
File "parser.pxi", line 1187, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.close    (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:87912)
File "parsertarget.pxi", line 130, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97055)
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 294, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:8862)
File "saxparser.pxi", line 274, in lxml.etree._handleSaxCData (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:93385)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 476: invalid start byte
```

Doing the following:

```
print repr(r.text[476 - 10: 476 + 10])
```

Produces:

```
u'ttp-equiv="X-UA-Comp'
```

I'm really not sure what the issue here is. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `r.content` instead? BeautifulSoup decodes for you, but `r.text` returns Unicode.

Comment: See my comment below. That seems to fail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text` on a response returns a decoded unicode value, but perhaps you should let BeautifulSoup do the decoding for you:

```
p = BeautifulSoup(r.content, from_encoding=r.encoding)
```

`r.content` returns the un-decoded raw bytestring, and `r.encoding` is the encoding detected from the headers.

Comment: >>> p = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @user1622821: I cannot reproduce your issues with that URL, btw. Your example works for me, as does mine.

Comment: Would this have something to do with my local installation? I'm on CrunchBang running Python 2.6.6 with the latest version of libxml and libxslt installed. I installed BeautifulSoup4, requests, and lxml with easy_install.